# Does Expdp utility requires EXP_FULL_DATABASE privilege while exporting the same schema over network link

Tags: oracle, oracle-dump

I am using `expdp` utility over a network link. I need to export only one schema which I own. ideally, it should allow me to export the schema which I own. But I am getting error like

ORA-31631: privileges are required
ORA-39149: cannot link privileged user to non-privileged user

So do we need EXP_FULL_DATABASE privilege for exporting the same schema?

Comment: Tell us more about the dblink: created on the tarket (importing) database? Which user on both db?

Comment: i have a remote server with a schema named schema1 . so i have created one network link on my local db with remote db credential(user =schema1 , password =1234) . Then i used this link in network_link param along with schemas=schema1 . but still i got the error even though i am exporting the same schema by which i have created the network link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the local and remote users require the **EXP_FULL_DATABASE** role granted to them while using NETWORK_LINK switch in data pump.

Check the following confirming the same:
http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g.php

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no, depends on privilege you gave to *target* schema:

> If the USERID that is executing the import job has the DATAPUMP_IMP_FULL_DATABASE role on the target database, then that user must also have the DATAPUMP_EXP_FULL_DATABASE role on the source database. (from http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_import.htm)

So you could either remove the DATAPUMP_IMP_FULL_DATABASE role from the target schema, or give the DATAPUMP_EXP_FULL_DATABASE role to source schema.

Comment: Thanks for help. The solution is to REVOKE privileges on test. Quite surprising but functional.